# Can't pass property value into private object's contructor

Tags: .net, vb.net, properties, smtpclient

I'm trying to create a custom smtp class using the existing System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient but somehow it's not picking up property values which was set outside of the class.

```
Public Class CustomClient
   Implements IDisposable

   Private smtpClient As System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient

   Public Property FromAddress As String
   Public Property ToAddress As String
   Public Property Subject As String
   Public Property Body As String
   Public Property MtaIP As String

   Public Sub New()

      Me.smtpClient = New Net.Mail.SmtpClient(MtaIP, 25) 'SmtpClient's Host field is still empty after initializationa
      smtpClient.EnableSsl = False
      smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = True
      smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
   End Sub

   Public Sub SendMessage()
     Try
        Using message As New MailMessage(FromAddress, ToAddress)

            message.Subject = Subject
            message.Body = "TEST"
            message.BodyTransferEncoding = Net.Mime.TransferEncoding.QuotedPrintable
            smtpClient.Send(message)
        End Using
     Catch ex As Exception
        Dim errorMsg As String = " SMTPClient encountered the following error..." &
               vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Exception Information:" & vbNewLine & BuildExceptionReport(ex)
        CourierShared.Common.sendMessage(errorMsg, MessageTypes.Failure)
    End Try
  End Sub

End Class
```

Above is my code. I confirmed MtaIP's value is correctly passed over from outside, but somehow it's throwing exception complaining hostname is not specified. When I change the property to public field instead and assign value manually, it works fine.

Am I missing something with property usage?

Edit: I added more specific send method in CustomClient object and below is how I use the class to send the message

```
Public Class CustomClientTest
  Public Sub Test()
     Using client As New CustomClient()
         client.FromAddress = inboundSender
         client.ToAddress = inboundRecipient
         client.Subject = inboundMsgSubject
         client.MtaIP = "123.234.34.56" 'I use actual host that works but put this as a reference
         client.SendMessage()
     End Using
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Property assignment can't happen before your constructor fires--think about it:  does that even make sense--so your property is `Nothing` inside the constructor. Pass the value as a constructor parameter if you need access to the value in the constructor.

Comment: MtaIP doesn't have a value yet in the constructor.

Comment: Properties such as `MtaIP` wont exist until after the constructor runs.  You could pass any required info to your wrapper via the constructor.

Comment: @JNA Out of interest - ***how*** did you confirm `MtaIP's value is correctly passed over from outside`? A correct way to would be to put a breakpoint inside the constructor and inspect the value of `MTaIP` at that moment in time.

Comment: @RB. Yes that's exactly how I confirmed the value of MtaIP passed from outside

Comment: There is no way `MtaIP` could be set to anything other than `Nothing` inside the constructor because you're not setting it until _after_ the constructor has already run!  Setting it later inside your `Test` method will not cause the property in the `SmtpClient` client class to change.  It is still `Nothing` when you instantiate it.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway ahhh thanks! I wish I could select the comment as an answer. I changed the constructor of CustomClient to take mtaIP directly instead. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your Properties have no `Get` and/or `Set` methods.  For example:

```
Private mFromAddress as string

Public Property FromAddress () As String
    Get
        FromAddress = mFromAddress 
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        mFromAddress = value
    End Set
End Property
```

In your external code you first instantiate the class:

```
Dim MySMTPClient as  SMTPClient
' Now you can set the property
MySMTPClient.FromAddress = "SomeEmailAddress"
```

Comment: .net is supposed to auto assign those now, isn't it? Btw, I added more details and how I use it. Pretty much same as you mentioned.

Comment: Since VS 2013 the `Get` and `Set` methods are not automatically generated.  You have to do that yourself.

Comment: This is not correct re: properties.  @JNA is correct, in VB, there is no need for a `Get` or `Set`.  The OP properties are declared correctly as auto properties for which the syntax is `Public Property Name As DataType`

Comment: @Chris Dunaway "You cannot initialize an auto-implemented property that is a member of an `Interface`, or one that is marked `MustOverride`", see the link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/auto-implemented-properties

Comment: Nowhere is the OP initializing the auto-property nor is it part of an `Interface` or marked `MustOverride` so I'm not sure what you are trying to tell me.

Comment: `IDisposable` is an interface.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I'm still not sure what your point is.  Just because the class implements the `IDisposable` interface, doesn't mean that its auto properties cannot be initialized using the simpler syntax.  And in any case, the OP is not attempting to initialize the auto properties anyway.